# How to identify Java keywords, operators and comments in a Java source using stream tokenize

Tags: java, parsing

I am trying to read a **Java source file** and then **identify all the Java keywords, identifiers and operators** in it. I tried to declare all the keywords and operators in an array and then check if that TT_word contains it or not. But I am unable to identify identifiers, help with examples highly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you want to write a java lexer.

Comment: You're going to have a write a parser / lexer, or use an existing one. You [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999979/how-to-write-a-java-program-to-identify-keywords-operators-and-identifiers-in-a) a similar question the other day, so this looks very much like a course in Compilers that you are taking. Therefore, I suspect you *can't* use an existing one, and must write one yourself. That's your homework, and you won't learn anything if you don't do it by yourself. Maybe your course is expecting you to use ANTLR, that's common for a class like this these days? Only you know though.

Comment: You're going to have to use a much more robust approach than simply tokenizing the input. Without doing at least some parsing of the code according to the Java language grammar, you're not going to be able to even distinguish between occurrences of keywords in code and in comments.

Comment: @TedHopp i agree with you

Comment: @Ted Hopp: Exactly. And quoted strings.

Comment: @TedHopp: Eh?  If he "tokenizes" the input, identifiers, keywords and comments will be clearly treated as separate entities, with no confusion.  No parser needed. Even if he cares to find the text for keywords in comments, he doesn't need a parser; he merely needs a post-lexing step that searches already-identified comment text for keyword names.  (And that the same exact process used to do lexical analysis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to look at something lexer or parser solutions. Writing this yourself is going to be very painful compared to some of the already existing solutions - if you want to still write your own - feel free to comment back and I'll leave a detailed answer on how to get started. However, I would recommend looking at something like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Comment: String[] keywordArray = {"this","protected","public","return","try","static","while","throw","throws","void","for","abstract","new","switch","synchronized","boolean","break","byte","case","catch","char","class","do","if","double","else","extends","final","finally","float","private","implements","import","instanceof","int","short","long","super"};
        String[] operatorArray = {"==","!=","=","+","-","/","%","*","++","--","!",">",">=","<","<=","&&","||","?:","~","<<",">>",">>>","&","^","|"};

Comment: ase StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
                   if(keywordList.contains(st.sval)){
                       System.out.println("Keyword is: "+st.sval+" at line number: "+st.lineno());
                   }

Comment: If you have a better approach - I encourage you to post your own answer @f1r3wall

Comment: i am trying to do this way, but i am kinda stuck in identifying isentifier, so wanted some help and also need some explaation on identiying block comments and commets. i need to identify and print those with line numbers..

Comment: @f1r3wall I'd encourage you to edit your post, then to include these details.

Comment: @f1r3wall: You **have** to use or write a parser and a lexer!

Answer (score 1):

PMD which is used to write static code analysis rules does something similar as you might need. PMD also parses the source code.

Please download the source code and have a look. Might be useful

http://pmd.sourceforge.net

Comment: PMD *parses*?  Lexes, maybe.